xsel like a clipboard manager: keep clipboard content for future use
I'd like to run xsel as background process to keep clipboard content for future use. I run it in openbox startup script like that:
xsel -b -k

But when I select something with Ctrl-C and close original application, there is nothing in clipboard. Also I don't see xsel process in task manager.
What I'm doing wrong?
PS. I don't what to use parcellite of smth like that. Just simple shell scripts.

If you absolutely want to do this manually, this will provide a constant backup of your most recent copy.
#!/bin/bash

history_file="clipboard_history.txt"
last_item=""

>"$history_file"

add_to_history() {
    local item="$1"
    # empty or a duplicate check
    if [[ -n "$item" && "$item" != "$last_item" ]]; then
        last_item="$item"
        # writes to history file, overwriting previous content
        echo "$item" > "$history_file"
    fi
}

# copies the history to clipboard
copy_from_history() {
    local entry
    entry=$(<"$history_file")
    if [[ -n "$entry" ]]; then
        echo "$entry" | xclip -selection clipboard
    else
        echo "No recent entry in the history"
    fi
}

# infinite loop poll's every two seconds
while true; do
    clipboard_content=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)

    if [[ -n "$clipboard_content" ]]; then
        add_to_history "$clipboard_content"
    fi

    sleep 2
done

Save as: clipkeeper.sh and change mode to executable chmod +x clipkeeper.shUsage: ./clipkeeper.sh &disown
It will output task number and PID number:
[1] 123456

To stop it, type pkill 123456. Use the PID number in the terminal, of course.That should do it!

Finally, I've found the solution.
xsd is based on xclipd and fixes this issue in it.
I run xsd in startup script and both clipboard and file copy using "Ctrl-C-Ctrl-V" work fine.

If you just want your clipboard to work, you should run a clipboard manager.
The lightest one I know of is xclipd. Try this:

Clone the xclipd repository and cd to the folder.
Run make.
Now run ./xclipd.

Until you terminate xclipd, the clipboard will stay alive: you can use it even if the original application quits.
The clipboard is officially called the CLIPBOARD selection, and the reason you’re losing the clipboard is that selections are peer-to-peer. By default, the applications are playing football with the CLIPBOARD selection: if the selection belongs to program 1 and you copy or paste something in program 2, program 2 steals the selection from program 1. If you terminate a program while it’s holding the selection, the selection dies along with the program.
What a clipboard manager does is keep track of each selection from a central place, hold onto the contents in case an application quits, and answer the applications’ requests for copying and pasting and so on.
The answer to a similar question here has a good explanation of the clipboard under X, and the answer here on AskUbuntu has a good reading list for learning more.

Thanks! Initially it seemed to me that this was exactly what I was looking for. Text was copied between applications without any problems. However, I discovered that for some unknown reason, copying files in Spacefm via 'Ctrl-C Ctrl-V' stopped working...

Glad you found a solution!
